# How should I deal with space character when using split

Tags: java, regex, file, split

So apparently when I am using `S.split(" ")` and I have `" "` (space) in my code file, it gets ignored. I was wondering if there's a way to overcome that. What I had in mind and is written in the following code doesn't work however it works for every other character.

```
String codeArr[] =code.split("\\r?\\n");           
        int k=0;
        while (k<codeArr.length-1)
        {


            String[] tmpCode=codeArr[k].split(" ");

            if (tmpCode.length!=2)
                HuffCodeToCh.put(tmpCode[0]," ");
            else 
                HuffCodeToCh.put(tmpCode[1],tmpCode[0]);
            k+=1;
        }
```

My input is of the following type (in a file):

```
i 000
r 001
e 01
s 100
n 101
. 110000
" 110001
E 1100100
k 11001010
H 11001011
f 110011
t 1101
  1110
a 111100
```

I want to save the character as well as its binary code in a hashMap as shown in the code. However the code I have written above doesn't save `" "` in the hashmap. I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Can you give me a hint rather than just BLINDLY voting down?

Comment: Not the downVoter.. *it gets ignored* - is wrong.. `split()` splits the line based on the regex passed and *returns an array*

Comment: -1, bad code formatting (messed up indentation, confusing vertical whitespace, no spaces around operators), no debugging efforts identifiable, ...

Comment: when splitting on a char/line/regex, the resulting array will not contain what you've split on

Comment: I think "the space" means the first char of the second to last line of the input.

Comment: Not that it solves anything but why do you read text first and then split its lines instead of handling each line while reading it? Scanner methods `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` could be very useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
codeArr[k].split(" (?=\\S)");
```

so that

```
x 100 -> {"x","100"}
  100 -> {" ","100"}
   11 -> {"  ", "11"} (two spaces)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-).

```
String c = codeArr[k].substring(0, 1);
String b = codeArr[k].substring(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, your whole loop is simply:

```
for (String line : code.split("\\r?\\n"))
  HuffCodeToCh.put("" + line.charAt(0), line.substr(2));
```

On a largely unrelated note, your variable `HuffCodeToCh` does not follow Java naming conventions, which strongly suggest that initial capitals be reserved for types.